# How do I reimplement (or wrap) a syscall function on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, libc

Suppose I want to completely take over the open() system call, maybe to wrap the actual syscall and perform some logging. [One way to do this is to use LD_PRELOAD](http://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2007/11/17/using-ld_preload-libraries-and-glibc-backtrace-function-for-debugging/) to load a (user-made) shared object library that takes over the open() entry point.

The user-made open() routine then obtains the pointer to the glibc function `open()` by `dlsym()`ing it, and calling it.

The solution proposed above is a dynamic solution, however. Suppose I want to link my own `open()` wrapper statically. How would I do it? I guess the mechanism is the same, but I also guess there will be a symbol clash between the user-defined `open()` and the libc `open()`.

Please share any other techniques to achieve the same goal.

Comment: How about you just stick a wrapper function/macro in your code?

Comment: @Seamus : I prefer not to use macros. I don't really have a problem. I am asking just to increase SO knowledge and learn some new trick.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the wrap feature provided by `ld`. From `man ld`:

> `--wrap symbol` Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to
>   `symbol` will be resolved to `__wrap_symbol`.
>
> Any undefined reference to `__real_symbol` will be resolved to `symbol`.

So you just have to use the prefix `__wrap_` for your wrapper function and `__real_` when you want to call the real function. A simple example is:

`malloc_wrapper.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void *__real_malloc (size_t);

/* This function wraps the real malloc */
void * __wrap_malloc (size_t size)
{
    void *lptr = __real_malloc(size);
    printf("Malloc: %lu bytes @%p\n", size, lptr);
    return lptr;
}
```

Test application `testapp.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    free(malloc(1024)); // malloc will resolve to __wrap_malloc
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile the application:

```
gcc -c malloc_wrapper.c
gcc -c testapp.c
gcc -Wl,-wrap,malloc testapp.o malloc_wrapper.o -o testapp
```

The output of the resulting application will be:

```
$ ./testapp
Malloc: 1024 bytes @0x20d8010
```

Comment: It looks that function that calls malloc cannot be dynamically linked. For example, I wrote a tools.c, which contains a function perform_alloc() which calls malloc. Then if I make a libtools.so first and link it dynamically by `-ltools`, `-Wl,-wrap,malloc` will not work.

Comment: As answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826108/has-anyone-an-example-for-wrapping-a-function-in-c it is required to prefix the function definitions with `extern "C"` when using this code in a C++ program.

Comment: Does the function have to be called `__wrap_malloc`? Or can it be named differently? What I mean is when wrapping system calls, do we have to name the functions same as the actual call?

Comment: @return0: as `man ld` shows, symbols must have the prefixes `__wrap_` and `__real_`.

Answer (score 3):

Symbols are resolved by the linker in the order you list them on the command line so if you listed your library before the standard library you'd have precidence. For gcc you'd need to specify

```
gcc <BLAH> -nodefaultlibs <BLAH BLAH> -lYOUR_LIB <OTHER_LIBS>
```

This way your libraries would be searched and found first.

Answer (score 0):

For linux and GNU libc, the library has built-in support for intercepting and reimplementing any function in the library.

If you define you own version of ANY libc function, and link it before libc (so have it part of your executable, or in a library linked before -lc on the link command or even loaded with `LD_PRELOAD` if libc is dynamically linke), it will be called instead of the libc version (even calls in other function in libc itself).  You can then call the function with a `__libc_` prefix to get the actual version in the library (though you will need to declare that symbol yourself.)  For example:

```
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/stat.h>
       #include <fcntl.h>

       extern int __libc_open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

       int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode) {
           return __libc_open(pathname, flags, mode);
       }
```