# Has anyone an example for wrapping a function in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I have searched online a lot but I couldn't find an example that works with g+, all examples work with GCC.

The error I keep getting is:

```
wrap_malloc.o: In function `__wrap_malloc(unsigned int)':
wrap_malloc.cc:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `__real_malloc(unsigned int)'
wrap_malloc.o: In function `main':
wrap_malloc.cc:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `__wrap_malloc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code that creates this error is the following (this code works if I compile it with GCC and change the headers from cstdio to stdio.h):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void *__real_malloc(size_t);

void *__wrap_malloc(size_t c) {
  printf("My malloc called with %d\n", c);
  return __real_malloc(c);
}

int main(void) {
  void *ptr = malloc(12);
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

This is how I compile it:

```
wrap_malloc.o: wrap_malloc.cc
    g++ -c wrap_malloc.cc -o wrap_malloc.o

wrap_malloc: wrap_malloc.o
    g++ wrap_malloc.o -o wrap_malloc -Wl,--wrap,malloc
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use a C++ compiler, all names are mangled. What this means becomes clear when you run `nm wrap_malloc.o`, which should give you something like this:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
         U __Z13__real_mallocj
00000000 T __Z13__wrap_mallocj
         U _printf
```

This means that you use (**U**) a symbol called `__Z13__real_mallocj` and that you define a symbol in the text segment (**T**) called `__Z13__wrap_mallocj`. But you probably want a symbol called `__real_malloc`. To achieve this you have to say the compiler that `__real_malloc` is a C-style function, like this:

```
extern "C" void *__real_malloc(size_t);

extern "C" void *__wrap_malloc(size_t c) {
  printf("My malloc called with %d\n", c);
  return __real_malloc(c);
}
```

Now the output of `nm` is:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 t .text
         U ___real_malloc
00000000 T ___wrap_malloc
         U _printf
```

You can see that the name `_printf` hasn't changed. This is because in the header files, many functions are declared as `extern "C"` already.

Note: I did all of the above on Windows in the cygwin environment. That's why there is an additional leading underscore in the external symbols.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand the problem.

Answer (score -3):

If this is the complete code, the problem you are having is that you haven't implemented `__real_malloc()`!

And by the way, identifiers with double-underscores are reserved by the language.  You might want to think about picking different names.

Comment: This code is a demo, I am planning to use the wrappers just for testing. If the code is compiled with --wrap=malloc it will redirect all the calls to __wrap_malloc. If you want to use the real thing you have to call __real_malloc. Here is the documentation => Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to "__wrap_ symbol ". Any undefined reference to "__real_ symbol " will be resolved to symbol.
This can be used to provide a wrapper for a system function. The wrapper function should be called "__wrap_ symbol ". If it wishes to call the system function, it should call "__real_ symbol ".