# Porting a C library to Python via ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes, porting

I've read in a lot of places that C-libraries can be ported to or written in python using the ctypes module from the standard library.

I've gone through the help('ctypes') page and from what I could gather I can create some of the C structures in Python, but my question is how do I use these to access the underlying system calls? For eg. when trying to port something like 'sys/if.h' to Python?

Can someone point me to good resources/documentation regarding the same?

Comment: Why not use Cython / Pyrex?

Comment: I'm not very sure about this but I think Cython requires a separate Cython compiler/interpreter? I can't use that as part of my project. But I'd appreciate any info regarding Cython as an alternative too.

Comment: It does, but is done by being installed into Python itself like any regular module: `python setup.py install`. The only requirement is that it needs a C compiler. As from [here](http://wiki.cython.org/Installing).

Answer (score 3):

If you want access to the system calls you could do something like this:

```
>>> from ctypes import CDLL
>>> libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
>>> print libc.strlen('abcde')
5
```

Reference: http://blog.bstpierre.org/using-pythons-ctypes-to-make-system-calls

**Or (This is the tricky part)**

Wrap a system call as outlined here into your C code:

[How to reimplement (or wrap) a syscall function in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662856/how-to-reimplement-or-wrap-a-syscall-function-in-linux)

And, then write a compliant source code file which will be used by CTypes, as per here:

http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Ctypes

I hope this helps.

Comment: I shall try this before I accept the answer. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: No problem, @Ayos - that's the whole point of Stackoverflow. ;)