# Passing custom flags to "open" in a device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, system-calls

I need to pass some custom flags to the `open()` call of my device driver.

I found this example in LDD3:

```c
int dev_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    if ((filp->f_flags & O_ACCMODE) == O_WRONLY) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is: is it possibile to define other flags (like `O_ACCMODE` and `O_WRONLY`) without conflicts with any others?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at [include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h). Pay attention to next comment:

```c
/*
 * When introducing new O_* bits, please check its uniqueness in fcntl_init().
 */
```

Now look into `fcntl_init()` function (defined at [fs/fcntl.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/fcntl.c#L736)):

```c
/*
 * Please add new bits here to ensure allocation uniqueness.
 * Exceptions: O_NONBLOCK is a two bit define on parisc; O_NDELAY
 * is defined as O_NONBLOCK on some platforms and not on others.
 */
BUILD_BUG_ON(20 - 1 /* for O_RDONLY being 0 */ != HWEIGHT32(
    O_RDONLY        | O_WRONLY      | O_RDWR        |
    O_CREAT         | O_EXCL        | O_NOCTTY      |
    O_TRUNC         | O_APPEND      | /* O_NONBLOCK | */
    __O_SYNC        | O_DSYNC       | FASYNC        |
    O_DIRECT        | O_LARGEFILE   | O_DIRECTORY   |
    O_NOFOLLOW      | O_NOATIME     | O_CLOEXEC     |
    __FMODE_EXEC    | O_PATH        | __O_TMPFILE
    ));
```

So first you need to find unique value for your new definition, so it can be bitwise-or'd with flags listed in `fcntl_init()`. Next you need to add your new definition to `include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h`. And finally add your new define to `fcntl_init()`, so it will be checked at compile time.

In the end it boils down to finding the value that doesn't conflict with existing definitions. E.g. as I can see all 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 and 10000000 are used. So for your new flags you can use 100000000, 200000000, 400000000 and 800000000 values.

**UPDATE**: As [SailorCaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036361/sailorcire) correctly mentioned, you also need to increment first number in `BUILD_BUG_ON()` macro. For example, if it originally was `BUILD_BUG_ON(20 - 1`, and you are to add one element to this list, you should make it `BUILD_BUG_ON(21 - 1`.

**UPDATE 2**: Another valuable addition from [SailorCaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036361/sailorcire):

> By the way, you'll need to do `make install_headers`, copy the new headers, and it looks like you'll need to recompile `glibc` so it becomes aware of the API change.

Comment: The only thing, is that despite doing these things, I'm still getting compile errors at the BUILD_BUG_ON..

Comment: @SailorCire What kind of compile errors do you have? Can you provide GCC output?

Comment: This will get ugly, but: `include/linux/compiler.h:484:20: error: call to ‘__compiletime_assert_758’ declared with attribute error: BUILD_BUG_ON failed: 20 - 1 != HWEIGHT32( O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O
_EXCL | O_NOCTTY | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND | __O_SYNC | O_DSYNC | FASYNC | O_DIRECT | O_LARGEFILE | O_DIRECTORY | O_NOFOLLOW | O_NOATIME | O_CLOEXEC | __FMODE_EXEC | O_PATH | __O_TMPFILE | __FMOD
E_NONOTIFY | O_CLASSIFY )
    prefix ## suffix();    \` I relooked at #define statements and noticed a pattern. I'm recompiling to see if that fixes that.

Comment: @SailorCire Why do you have `20 - 1` in the error, where it should probably be `22 - 1`? Also, what is the number that you assigned for `O_CLASSIFY`? BTW, you can use [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=75069f2b5bfb5164beafaf3da597279c25b5535a) commit as a template for your task.

Comment: I was using [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/643730/) as a basis and `O_CLASSIFY` is set to: `040000000`. I think you're right about the cause of the error. Sometimes I just need an extra set of eyes. I don't know why I decremented the value..

Comment: Yeah, that solved it...interesting that I made a point and didn't actually follow it. >_<

Comment: By the way, you'll need to do  make install_headers, copy the new headers, and it looks like you'll need to recompile glibc so it becomes aware of the API change.

Comment: Wow, good point! Totally missed it. Let me add it to the answer.

Comment: If you know of a way to have glibc be aware of the changes, without recompiling (and potentially breaking your system), then I'd love to know.

Comment: I'm not completely sure that glibc needs to be recompiled. As I see it, new constant only needs to be provided to `open()` syscall. Of course, if you don't want to mess with `open()` syscall, but rather use `fopen()` from standard library, it should be recompiled. So from my point of view it strongly depends on how you are planning to use newly added constant (possible use-cases).

Comment: if you did `syscall(SYS_open,...)`, then you'd be fine; however, if you do `open(2)` from `fcntl.h` then it doesn't know what the new values are.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure glibc doesn't check all flags in `open()` implementation, more like just passing them to actual syscall (btw, it's really hard to find which `open()` stub is used for x86_64 arch in glibc). Or I'm missing something? If you still need to override `open()` syscall -- you can do that using `--wrap` GCC option (look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662856/how-to-reimplement-or-wrap-a-syscall-function-in-linux)), or maybe using `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.

Comment: I've submitted a patch to address this. The data is pulled from `<bits/fcntl-linux.h>`. One could recompile their kernel and then modify <bits/fcntl-linux.h>; however, your package manager will blast it away when there is a new version of glibc. I'd suggest installing a new version in `/usr/local/` to avoid this.

Comment: @SailorCire Interesting. Can you please share a link to your patch here?