# Can I modify an existing syscall without recompiling the linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm looking to modify the flags for `open(2)` without having to recompile the kernel.

I have modified the [source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31022127/1036361) to change the flags, but having to recompile is a pain.

Is there a way to create a module, so that when I call `open(2)` I can pass in new flags "on the fly"?

I've seen where a program can intercept a system call and do something with existing flags; however, if I don't have the new flags, then I won't know if I should do anything with the interception.

I don't think it is possible, because of linking; however, I don't know.