# Can I intercept normal stdio calls in a C program, do some work and then call the original ones?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, stdio

I have a bunch of C files that try to read and write CSV and other random data to and from disk using stdio functions like `fread()`, `fwrite()`, `fseek()`. (If it matters, it's for a university assignment where we are to experiment with IO performance using different block sizes, and various structures to track data on disk files and so on.)

What I wanted to do was compile these source files (there are dozens of them) 
without the definitions for `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()` that come from `<stdio.h>`. I want to supply my own `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()` where I track some information, like which process tried to read which file, and how many blocks/pages where read and things like that, and then call the normal stdio functions.

I don't want to have to go through every line of every file and change `fopen()` to `my_fopen()` .... is there better way to do this at compile time?

I am half way working on a Python program that scans the source files and changes these calls with my functions but it's getting a bit messy and I am kind of lost. I thought maybe there is a better way to do this; if you could point me in the right direction, like what to search for that would be great.

Also I don't want to use some Linux profiling stuff that reports which syscalls where made and what not; I just want to execute some code before calling these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to the LD_PRELOAD trick (which requires you to write a separate library and works only on Linux) you can use the `--wrap` option of the GNU linker. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3662856/214671) for an example of this technique.

Main differences with LD_PRELOAD:

- no external library needed - it's all in the executable;
- no runtime options needed;
- works on any platform as long as you are using the GNU toolchain;
- works only for the calls that are resolved at link time - dynamic libraries will still use the original functions

Answer (score 1):

No but yes but no. The best way I know of is to [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) a library that provides your own versions of those functions. You can get at the originals by `dlopen`ing libc.so (the dlopen NULL trick to get at libc functions isn't applicable here because your library will have already been loaded).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is by redefining all the stdio functions you need. fopen becomes my_fopen, fread becomes my_fread, then have your my_fopen call fopen. This can be done in a header file that you include in the files where you want to replace the calls to fopen. See example below.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
  FILE *f;
  char buf[256];
  f = fopen("test.cvs", "r");
  if(f == NULL)
  {
      printf("Couldn't open file\n");
      return 1;
  }
  fread(buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), f);
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

my_stdio.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *my_fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
  FILE *fp;
  printf("%s before fopen\n", __FUNCTION__);
  fp = fopen(path,mode);
  printf("%s after fopen\n", __FUNCTION__);
  return fp;
}

int my_fclose(FILE *fp)
{
  int rv;

  printf("%s before fclose\n", __FUNCTION__);
  rv = fclose(fp);
  printf("%s after fclose\n", __FUNCTION__);
  return rv;
}

size_t my_fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
  size_t s;

  printf("%s before fread\n", __FUNCTION__);
  s = fread(ptr,size,nmemb,stream);
  printf("%s after fread\n", __FUNCTION__);
  return s;
}

size_t my_fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
  size_t s;

  printf("%s before fwrite\n", __FUNCTION__);
  s = fwrite(ptr,size,nmemb,stream);
  printf("%s after fwrite\n", __FUNCTION__);
  return s;
}
```

my_stdio.h:

```
#ifndef _MY_STDIO_H_
#define _MY_STDIO_H_

#define fopen my_fopen
#define fclose my_fclose
#define fread my_fread
#define fwrite my_fwrite

#endif /* _MY_STDIO_H_ */
```

Makefile:

```
main: main.o my_stdio.o
    $(CC) -g -o $@ main.o my_stdio.o

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -g -c -o $@ $<

my_stdio.o: my_stdio.c my_stdio.h
    $(CC) -g -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Bad idea to `gcc -Dfopen=my_fopen`, the `fopen` token inside `<stdio.h>` and `<bits/stdio.h>` will be replaced by `my_fopen`. A better idea is to `#define fopen my_fopen` inside `my_stdio.h` which should always be included after `<stdio.h>`

Comment: But that would require changes to all files that uses stdio.h. Why would replacing fopen to my_fopen in stdio.h be a problem? The code will call my_fopen anyway?

Comment: @Puppe: having seen the macro machinery at work in many standard headers, I wouldn't be comfortable replacing anything in them, and surely not names of standard functions.

Comment: I see your points, have updated my example to do the redefinition in my_stdio.h instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:  Add `-Dfread=my_fread` to the Makefile CFLAGS for any .o files you wish to "spy" on.  Add in my_fread.o that defines `my_fread` [which has *no* `-D` tricks].

Repeat the above for any functions you wish to intercept.  About the same as the `LD_PRELOAD` [in terms of effectiveness and probably easier to implement].  I've done both.

Or create a `my_func.h` that does the defines and insert a `#include "my_func.h"` in each file.  Dealer's choice

**UPDATE**

Forgot about another way.  Compile normally.  Mangle the symbol names in the target .o's [symbol table] (via a custom program or ELF/hex editor):  Change `fread` into something with the same length that doesn't conflict with anything [you can control this].  Target name: `qread` or `frea_` or whatever.

Add your intercept .o's using the new names.

This might seem "dirty", but what we're doing here *is* a "dirty" job.  This is an "old school" [sigh :-)] method that I've used for .o's for which I didn't have the source and before `LD_PRELOAD` existed.

Comment: "About the same as the LD_PRELOAD" nope, it's a completely different technique (brutal text substitution vs changing the way the loader works) with different applicability and different drawbacks. Saying they are about the same is seriously misleading.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I don't think that's quite what he meant to imply. Anyway it's a valid approach, and simpler in some ways. Biggest caveat is that it won't intercept function calls made by libraries, unless they were also rebuilt.

Comment: @MatteoItalia In terms of effectiveness they are about the same.  The "brutal" text substitution is actually quite easy.  If you do LD_PRELOAD, you have to do `dlopen` and `dlsym` [in your intercept function] which actually takes more work and you have to maintain state information.  BTW, somebody else proposed the same solution and got the accepted answer.